# probability puzzle, expected payoff for game

Tags: probability

This was a question at a programming contest that finished recently at interviewstreet:

> Alice and Bob play a game. The operations at round $i$ ($i ≥ 1$) is as follows:
>
> - Alice pays Bob $2i - 1$ dollars,
> - Alice tosses a biased coin,
> - If the result of the coin was heads for $k$ consecutive rounds, the game stops, otherwise the game continues.
>
> Given $k$ and the probablity $p$ that the outcome of a toss is heads, your program should find the expected number of dollars Alice pays Bob, and also the expected number of rounds played.

I had gotten the first part of the problem, i.e the expected number of rounds of the game. I got it with the following code

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = int(raw_input())   
    while t :
        t -= 1
        temp = str(raw_input())
        p,k = temp.split(' ')
        p = float(p)
        k = int(k)
        num = k * (p**k)
        den = 1
        q = 1.0 - p
        for N in range(1,k+1):
            den = den - ((p**(N-1))*q)
            num = num + (N*(p**(N-1))*q)
            #print (N*(q**N))

        print int(num/den)
```

But the second part of the problem is still puzzling me, i.e the expected number of dollars Alice pays bob. How can expected payoff be calculated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call $N$ the number of rounds played, then the number of dollars paid by Alice is $N^2$. The usual one-step recursion yields
$$
\mathrm E_i(s^N)=s(p\mathrm E_{i+1}(s^N)+(1-p)\mathrm E_0(s^N)),
$$
for every $0\leqslant i\leqslant k-1$, with $\mathrm E_k(s^N)=1$. One is after $\mathrm E_0(N)$ and $\mathrm E_0(N^2)$ and the linear system above yields
$\mathrm E_0(s^N)=u(s)$ with
$$
u(s)=\frac{(1-ps)(ps)^k}{1-s+(1-p)s(ps)^k}=1-(1-s)\frac{1-(ps)^k}{1-s+(1-p)s(ps)^k},
$$
hence $u'(1)=\mathrm E_0(N)$, that is,
$$
\mathrm E_0(N)=\frac{1-p^k}{(1-p)p^k}.
$$
Similarly, $u''(1)=\mathrm E_0(N(N-1))$. This yields a slightly more complicated, but explicit, formula for $\mathrm E_0(N^2)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't quite understand, some of the notation, what is s, and how did you calculate u(s)?

Comment: The argument $s$ can be any number such that $|s|\leqslant1$. One computes $u(s)$ by considering, for each such $s$, the affine system the vector $(\mathrm E_i(s^N))_{0\leqslant i\leqslant k}$ solves.